# Deploy ServiceBus with multiple Topics and Queues at once

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager

I'm fairly new to using the servicebus and other Azure features. After creating a servicebus manually on the Azure portal, I try to figure out how this can be achieved automatically. After a while of reading I thought that using the azure resource manager should be the way to go. Deploying just one topic is no big deal. But I can't find an example, that shows how to deploy multiple topics and queues at once. Or am I on the wrong approach?

Thanks for your answers!
Helmut

Comment: Do you want to create multiple queues + topic in the same resource group ? Using different namespaces ?

Answer (score 2):

What we do (and I saw other teams doing the same) is simple: when your producer/consumer application starts, it checks if required queues/topics/subscriptions exist, and creates them otherwise.

So we create all Service Bus entities from C# code, which also gives the full flexibility for options.

Code sample:

```cs
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists(topicName))
{
    namespaceManager.CreateTopic(new TopicDescription(topicName));
    namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(
        new SubscriptionDescription(topicName, subscriptionName));
}
```

That's not to say your ARM approach is wrong or bad, just to give a simple alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this was also the alternative I thought about. I think I will do the same in may application!

Answer (score 0):

Using the new azure portal ([here](https://portal.azure.com)), there is an `Automation script` feature.

I've created a new resource group with a service bus namespace that contains 2 topics and 1 queue:

[image: Azure Portal - ServiceBus - Preview]

You can see on the left panel, there is an `Automation script` feature.

[image: Azure Portal - ServiceBus - Automation script]

In this section, you can find a template that represents the resources that you've created manually. you can then use this template to automate your deployment to others environment.

See also [Deploy resources with Resource Manager templates and Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy)