# How Do I Create Multiple Service Bus Topics Using Multiple ARM Templates?

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I was wondering if there was a quick and dirty way to create new topics on an already-created Service Bus using a separate template?

Lets assume I have 2 templates, both with their own respective resources. Now, at the command prompt they have the option to deploy template1, template2, or BOTH. If template1 is selected, it should deploy its resources along with a Service Bus and a topic named 'Topic-Template1' -- And if template2 is chosen, it should do the same, but with a topic named 'Topic-Template2' -- However, if 'BOTH' is chosen as the parameter value, then I would like to deploy ONE Service Bus still, but now have TWO topics: 'Topic-Template1' & 'Topic-Template2'.

Is there a way to do this using only these two templates without them being nested and also assuming I'm doing so by calling for two new deployment commands in sequence from a PowerShell script if 'BOTH' is chosen

Assuming this is the logic in the PowerShell script for deploying template1 or template2:

```
# Determine which application to deploy
switch ($ApplicationDeployment.ToLower())
{ 
    #Deploys template1
    "template1" {
        New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "temp1-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                    -TemplateFile $temp1TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $temp1TemplateParametersFile `
                                    -Force -Verbose 2>> $temp1ErrorFileName | Out-File $temp1LogFileName -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages
    } 

    #Deploys template2
    "template2" {
        New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "temp2-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                    -TemplateFile $temp2TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $temp2TemplateParametersFile `
                                    -Force -Verbose 2>> $temp2ErrorFileName | Out-File $temp2LogFileName -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages 
    } 

    #Deploys both the template1 & template2 templates
    "both" {
        New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "temp1-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                    -TemplateFile $temp1TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $temp1TemplateParametersFile `
                                    -Force -Verbose 2>> $temp1ErrorFileName | Out-File $temp1LogFileName -ErrorVariable ErrorMessagess

        New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "temp2-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                    -TemplateFile $temp2TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $temp2TemplateParametersFile `
                                    -Force -Verbose 2>> $temp2ErrorFileName | Out-File $temp2LogFileName -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages
    }
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/44880682/4167200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with that, just create 2 templates and make them do what you are trying to make them do. It will just work.

But your approach is flawed at best, it is better to incorporate that logic in the template and make the template decide what to deploy based on your input